# How to get data from nested objects

Tags: javascript

```
var json = {
    "responseHeader": {
        "zkConnected": true,
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
    },
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": ["a", {
            "numFound": 6,
            "startOffset": 0,
            "endOffset": 1,
            "suggestion": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
        }]
    }
}
```

How to get suggestion from suggestions in this json using javaScript?

Comment: Show us the full code

Comment: `json.spellcheck.suggestions` ?

Comment: `json.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion`. JSON is just a combination of arrays and objects.

Comment: Sorry but this is not JSON. You code is like `var number = 'Red';`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, if you want to get full array

```
var allSuggestion = json.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion
```

or a specific value

```
var valueA = json.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion[0];
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8La6LgpL/)

Answer (score 0):

We can get all the suggestions by using

```
var Suggestions = json.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion
```

Or to get a position value you can use the index of it

```
var Suggestions = json.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion[index]
```

Also you can apply foreach loop to get the values or objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Simply looks in above picture for expressive structure of Array in Object.

If structure wrapped by `{}` that indicates its a Object So you can access property by `.`  which contains property name and its value (any type of value)

If wrapped by `[]` that indicate it is Array so you can access inner value by `[<index>]`. it contains set of value(any type of value) only.

Here `var json` is object because it wrapped by `{}` inner level property "responseHeader","spellcheck" are object because it's structure wrapped by `{}`, BUT you look into sub level "suggestions" is wrapped by [] so its array.

If you want to access value of `zkConnected` so your code should be

```
console.log(json.responseHeader.zkConnected);
```

If you want to access value of `numFound` so your code should be

```
console.log(json.spellcheck.suggestions[1].numFound);
```

Because in suggestions is array and have two value one is string "a" at index 0, and another is object at index 1.

If you want to access "e" of `suggestion` so your code should be

```
console.log(json.spellcheck.suggestions.suggestion[4]);
```

Because under suggestions, suggestion is array and e stands on 5th position so you can access it by index 4(position-1)

```
var json = {
    "responseHeader": {
        "zkConnected": true,
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
    },
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": ["a", {
            "numFound": 6,
            "startOffset": 0,
            "endOffset": 1,
            "suggestion": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
        }]
    }
}
```